# Запрос к БД

Tags: delphi, sql

При выполнении данной команды ругается на первую (и, видимо, все остальные) скобку в строке запроса. Что не так?

```
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.SQL.Add(Format('ALTER TABLE %s(%s    %s)'[edit1.Text,edit2.Text,combobox1.Text]));
try
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.ExecSQL;
except
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы бы написали что ваша alter table должна сделать, и я бы начал с изучения синтаксиса этой команды.

Comment: А вы ведь чертовски правы!
Извиняюсь за тупость, вопрос закрыт!